# Transfer Data from One Table to Another Based on Cell Values

Tags: arrays, excel, sorting, vba

I would like some help with a problem, which I imagine requires some VBA. I would like to transfer data from one table to another, based on a cell value that you can define.

[image]

Please refer to the image above for the description of the problem.

I would like to be able to 'store' the score data from each corresponding Team from the table on the right, to the table on the left depending on the week selected.

E.g. Team 2 has a score of 10 in Week 1, therefore, when I click the STORE button, I would like to store it in its corresponding spot on the table on the left. However for all teams.

Comment: *'which I imagine requires some VBA'* is not a specific programming question.

Comment: Sorry I was eluding to that I needed help with generating the code, I should have been clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly then the following code will loop through the TeamIDs and Scores and place them in the correct Week Number on the other table:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
Dim FoundID As Range, FoundID2 As Range
Dim TeamID As String, TeamID2 As String
Dim Score As String, Score2 As String

WeekNumber = ws.Range("M3").Value
'get WeekNumber to use for Offset

For i = 5 To 13
    TeamID = ws.Cells(i, 13)
    Score = ws.Cells(i, 15)
    TeamID2 = ws.Cells(i, 18)
    Score2 = ws.Cells(i, 16)
    Set FoundID = ws.Range("B3:B21").Find(What:=TeamID)
    If Not FoundID Is Nothing Then
        FoundID.Offset(0, WeekNumber).Value = Score
    End If
    Set FoundID2 = ws.Range("B3:B21").Find(What:=TeamID2)
    If Not FoundID2 Is Nothing Then
        FoundID2.Offset(0, WeekNumber).Value = Score2
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, the code you presented works perfectly, thank you!